# Paypal Integration for payments in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, paypal

I am trying to integrate paypal as payment in my android app but But i failed with some error like this .

> Error:(70, 5) error: no suitable method found for
>   startService(Intent,int) method ContextWrapper.startService(Intent) is
>   not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>   method Context.startService(Intent) is not applicable (actual and
>   formal argument lists differ in length)

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pay);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(
                Color.parseColor("#01bfff"));
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
        btnPayPal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPaypal);

        //Intent get value
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String currency = intent.getStringExtra("CURRENCY");
        int cost = intent.getIntExtra("COST", 0);
        txtCurrency.setText(currency);
        txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(" " + cost));

        btnPayPal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick (View v) {
    Intent in = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
    in.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

    startService(intent,0);
}public void onBuyPressed(View pressed) {

     PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("2"), "USD", "Total Ticket Price : ",
             PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

     Intent intnt = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
    intnt.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

     intnt.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);

     startActivityForResult(intnt, 0);
 }
 @Override
           protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
               if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                   PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                   if (confirm != null) {
                       try {
                           Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));




                       } catch (JSONException e) {
                           Log.e("paymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                       }
                   }
               }
               else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                   Log.i("paymentExample", "The user canceled.");
               }
               else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                   Log.i("paymentExample", "An invalid Payment or PayPalConfiguration was submitted. Please see the docs.");
               }
           }

        });
```

It returned  expected in

```
public void onClick (View v) {
Intent in = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
in.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

startService(intent,0);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You're doing wrong over here

```
startService(intent,0);
```

Change it to

```
startService(intent);
```

`startService(Intent)` has only one argument.

and more information refer [Official Service Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: Encounter this error :: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous OnClickListener>,Class<PayPalService>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri,Context,Class<?>) is not applicable.

Comment: @RajanKandel do  `Intent in = new Intent(YourActivity.this, PayPalService.class);`